# What is the opposite of a base class in OOP?

Tags: oop

In object-oriented programming, a 'base class' is a class from which other classes have been derived (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_class).

However, what is the opposite of a base class? In order words, what is a class that does NOT have any child classes called?

EDIT: I am looking for the name of a class that has not been sub-classed, YET, within an inheritance of tree of multiple parent classes, starting with a base class.

Comment: There is no need to have a term for that, it's just called a class.

Comment: There's a distinct difference between a class that *hasn't* been sub-classed and one that *can't* be subclassed. Which do you mean?

Comment: I am looking for the name of a class that hasn't been sub-classed, YET.

Comment: Interesting that so many did not understand the question. What could be considered tricky, though, is a class that derive from a _utility class_ as we have in C++. For example, you may derive from `enable_shared_from_this<>`. Do you still consider that class a base class? Or is it already a derived class?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A base class is a *relative* term. It only applies when considering one of its derived classes. Here are some terms that I consider opposites (and mostly orthogonal among themselves):

- base class vs derived class; similarly super class vs sub class
- abstract class vs concrete class
- root class vs leaf class
- sealed (also, final) class vs inheritable (non-sealed) class
- nested class vs top-level class

Abstract and (normally) root classes are designed to be base classes. Sealed classes *cannot* be base classes, because they're non-inheritable. A root class is a class without a base class (in C# and Java, this class is `Object`). A leaf class has no subclass, so it's not a base class; but it's not necessarily sealed. Sealed classes, on the other hand, are *always* leaf classes.

So,

> I am looking for the name of a class that has not been sub-classed, YET

It seems that you're looking for a **leaf class**, **but I don't consider it to be the opposite of a base class**.

Answer (score 4):

I usually hear leaf class. Java enforces it with `final`.

Answer (score 4):

It would be called a leaf class.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf_class_(computer_programming)

Comment: According to that link, a leaf is one that shouldn't or can't be subclassed--not one that isn't.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, these are called sealed classes. You can use the keyword `sealed` to indicate that a class is not to be inherited from. VB uses the keyword `NotInheritable`. Wikipedia calls them [non-subclassable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealed_class#Non-subclassable).

Answer (score 1):

I sealed class doesn't have to inherit from anything.  To me the opposite of a base class would be a derived class, but being a derived class doesn't preclude it from being inherited from.

But it sounds like Carl T.'s answer is probably what you were looking for.